# How do I use R version 3.0 when I have an updated version 3.1?

Tags: r, version

I was using R version 3.0 and on 2014-04-10 it got updated to the latest version 3.1.0 (Spring Dance). I was working on a package GenometriCorr and all my analyses was on version 3.0. Now if I open my .RData on the new version, it does not show a lot of objects because they were associated with the path of version 3.0.

I installed this package on version 3.1 but I have to re-run all my analyses again because the path has changed. And re-running the R code again is really not that easy. I have two folders in ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0 & ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1.

Can I use the old version of R again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the old workspace into your new version of R, with

```
> load("~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/.RData")
```

or whatever the filename is.

By the way, good practice is to not save your entire workspace by default to the ".RData" file, but to save just the parts you need to a file you name. See `?save`.

Comment: I don't know if this is going to help because firstly, the .RData file is stored somewhere else and secondly, by default when I start R or Rstudio, it loads up version 3.1.0. Whenever I try to load my .RData it get opened up in the latest version by default.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your new default .RData gets loaded; you can load the old one on top of it (though again, better to not save into the default workspace at all). So go find where your old .RData file is; the path I gave is likely but perhaps not accurate, and try loading it.